# How to order associated columns case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to order all my projects by their customer company names, but I get this error: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "customers" LINE 1: ... WHERE "projects"."archived" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(customers.... ^ : SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."archived" = $1 ORDER BY LOWER(customers.company) ASC`.

This is how I tried it so far:

```
projects = Project.includes(:customer).order("LOWER(customers.company) ASC")
```

If I leave out `LOWER(…)` everything works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write it using [`references`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references).

```
Project.includes(:customer)
       .order("LOWER(customers.company) ASC")
       .references(:customers)
```